# Running php -v on terminal opens up PhpStorm

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpstorm

When I try to check PHP version through terminal using `php -v` in Ubuntu, it opens up PhpStorm. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe try `which php` to see which binary is being called?

Comment: /usr/bin/php is being called

Comment: That definitely doesn't run phpstorm. Unless it's been changed to a symlink or something weird like that

Comment: What do you get if you do `ls -l /usr/bin/php`?

Comment: I get lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jun  1  2022 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php when I do ls -l usr/bin/php.

Comment: You might have to check a few more paths. `ls -l /etc/alternatives/php`, then `ls -l` whatever that file points to

Comment: ls -l /etc/alternatives/php leads to /usr/bin/php8.1 which seems to be correct php version and doing ls -l /usr/bin/php8.1 does not lead anywhere. That is the last path,

Comment: I'm stumped, then. You might have better luck on https://askubuntu.com , since it may have to do with system associations

Comment: Try running the finally binary literally, `/usr/bin/php8.1 --version`, just to see if that behaves weirdly, too

Comment: @ChrisHaas running /usr/bin/php8.1 --version shows "PHP 8.1.12 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2022 17:39:37) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
"
Does not seem to be behaving weirdly here

Comment: I agree that you might be better suited on a Linux forum, but the last option that I can think of is to run `alias` to see if you have an entry for `php` in there